# Sometimes screen is black whenever starting lenovo ideapad 320

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm having an issue with my Lenovo IdeaPad 320 i5 8th Gen that sometimes shows a black screen whenever I want to start it from `Hibernate` or by the power button press. Sometimes it works fine but it's very annoying when it doesn't show screen even after several attempts.

```
azizul@deapad:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

It has 2 graphics one is integrated Intel UHD 620 and another one is discrete - NVIDIA GEOFORCE

```
azizul@deapad:~$ lshw -c display
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

`nvidia-smi` shows error:

```
azizul@deapad:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

No additional drivers listed:

[image]

Benchmarking GPU:

```
azizul@deapad:~$ glxgears
310 frames in 5.0 seconds = 61.860 FPS
301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.012 FPS
301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.020 FPS
301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.007 FPS
301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.013 FPS
301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.014 FPS
301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.014 FPS
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the driver for Nvidia graphics card.

Open a terminal and write this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo apt update
```

then you will be able to install the driver via additional drivers. You can also install it directly with:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-410
```

It's better to install `dkms` before the driver because whenever the system kernel is updated, `dkms` will automatically rebuild the NVIDIA driver module for the new kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential
```

You didn't mention your Nvidia Graphics model but I think it's a GeForce MX150 and is in the list of supported graphics cards.

Comment: Hi @sadegh-6khan,
Please check the result in the pastebin

https://pastebin.com/G3ZR0SeA
https://pastebin.com/E4NcBrsy

Comment: @AzizulHaque your information showed that the last package is `nvidia-driver-410` so I updated the answer. everything else seemed ok to me. please mark as correct answer if it solved your problem.